# commandline tool to trim empty space from beginning of audio track?

Tags: unix, audio, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm wondering if it's possible with a commandline tool, (ffmpeg or other) to trim empty space from the beginning or end of an audio track. If anyone knows anything about this, that would some advice/info would be amazing. Thanks

Comment: How is the data stored? What container and audio codec?

Comment: I think you can do this with sox, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @multimedia mike either mp3 or wav

Answer (score 3):

Are you hoping to find a tool that *automatically* identifies and trims silence from the start of the track? That would be a little more complicated. However, if you know that you want to remove the first, e.g., 7.5 seconds of a PCM WAV file, use FFmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ss 7.5 output.wav
```

The same command generally applies for a .MP3 file. **However**, you have to be careful to avoid generational quality loss by inadvertently decompressing and then re-encoding the MP3 audio data. For this, you ask FFmpeg to copy the codec data rather than transcoding it:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 7.5 output.mp3
```

Comment: thanks...I do think that sox can do this though...I haven't quite figured out the right command...